# Apache Module blocking access to FTP

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd, ftp

I'm running a CentOs server with a lot of websites on it. The previous dev lead applied the Apache module to all domains.

Problem is, now the client can't access their files in Filezilla. They can view, but they can't edit, delete, or upload anything.

Originally the user permissions were ~domainuser~:psaserv, but this doesn't allow the CMS to run.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: What module are you referring to?Try using directives in a location block if you need to change how apache is handling a certain directory. It is not clear if your problem is with apache configuration or you are having a permissions issues where FileZilla is being denied access to modify the files.

Comment: It's a PHP Handler called Apache module. The site is on a DV Grid with a Plesk interface so I don't want to mess with any configuration files.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a few too many software layers there, but if you can't mess with the configuration that is beside the point. In that case, try running ps -ef | grep httpd (or apache) and see what user apache is running as. Make sure the user document root has that same permission and try FileZilla again.

Comment: There might be a way to work around it in Plesk, I just need a starting point (i.e. the root of the problem) to know what to change.

Comment: Let me try that comment again: try running ps -ef | grep httpd (or apache) and see what user apache is running as. Make sure the user document root has that same ownership and try FileZilla again.

Comment: Quick and dirty method is to change the ownership until you find something FileZilla likes.

Comment: The doc root has apache permissions. The problem is the site only runs with apache, while Filezilla needs the domain subscription's username (it's not possible to change this)

Comment: Well filezilla user has to exist on the system or you are SOL, so I am assuming username does exist on the system. Try adding that username to the same group as the apache user.

Comment: Like in /etc/groups

Comment: Obviously there is the security red flag any time you are including anyone in the same group as apache, but I don't think you can leave ownership as something that FileZilla doesn't like and still make it work. Aside from crazy permissions which would be much much worse.

Answer (score 0):

With a little digging I was able to resolve the problem. The domain was running PHP as Apache module. When I switched it back to FastCGI, I was able to restore the user permissions to ~username~:psaserv. After that FTP and web services work fine.